# How to prevent css from getting converted to inline css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using jquery to modify css of a div element on pressing a button. I noticed the css getting inline to the HTML. How can I prevent the style from getting inline ?

```
<style media="" data-href="../../dist/css/flat-ui.css">...</style>
```

These style tags appear on rendering.

Comment: Appending inline styles, It is the only way to modify css with jQuery (JavaScript). You can't change value in the css file on the fly.

Comment: Totally get it, is there a work around ?

Comment: None that I know of

Comment: If your CSS is static, then you can add the styles in an id/class and then assign them in `jquery` using `addClass()`.

Comment: When you say _I noticed the css getting inline to the HTML_, do you mean in the `body` element? .. You can control where it gets added, but the question is: "What problem are you trying to solve?"

Comment: Don't know what the issue is with jquery adding inline styles, but if you really want to avoid this you should be using addClass() like @Shashank is suggesting.

Comment: @LGSon Sounds like a X-Y problem to me.

Comment: @Terry Yes, think so too ... so I asked what problem the OP try to solve

Comment: @LGSon I am increasing the width of the div element on pressing the button. So, I've used css() to push the changes.

Comment: Ok, check my answer, updated with the simplest way _and_ some more advanced one's

Comment: Could you let me know what is not working with the answer a gave, so I will be able to adjust and you to accept?

Answer (score 0):

Link your `stylesheet` in head

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
```

Comment: Yes, I've already done that. The style tag get appended while rendering. It makes sense to become inline because that's the only way jquery can dynamically push css.

Comment: You're right and there is no way(that I know of) to prevent that from happening.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using jquery to modify css of a div element on pressing a button.

The most obvious would of course be to add/remove/toggle a class with a predefined rule, like this,

CSS

```
.wider {
  width: 500px;
}
```

Script

```
$( "element" ).toggleClass( "wider" );
```

but if that is not what you look for, you can add a style element dynamically, to override an existing rule

JS

```
function loadStyle(css) {
  var style = document.querySelector('style[id="lastinbody"]') || document.createElement('style');
  style.id = 'lastinbody';
  style.type = 'text/css';
  if (style.styleSheet){
    style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
  } else {
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
  }
  document.querySelector('body').appendChild(style);
}
```

Usage

```
loadStyle('.item { color: red; }');
```

---

> I noticed the css getting inline to the HTML.

If you want the style being added to the `head`, do like this

JS

```
function loadStyle(css) {
  var style = document.querySelector('head style[id="addedinhead"]') || document.createElement('style');
  style.id = 'addedinhead';
  style.type = 'text/css';
  if (style.styleSheet){
    style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
  } else {
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
  }
  document.querySelector('head').appendChild(style);
}
```

---

And here is how to push a CSS file

```
var style = document.createElement('link');
style.rel = 'stylesheet';
style.type = 'text/css';
style.media = 'screen';
style.href = 'css-file-path';
document.querySelector('head').appendChild(style);
```

---

And this one shows how to add to an existing linked stylesheet

HTML

```
<head>
  <link title="customCSS" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
```

JS

```
function setStyleSheetRule(title, rule) {
  for(var i=0; i<document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = document.styleSheets[i];
    if(sheet.title == title) {
      sheet.insertRule(rule, sheet.cssRules.length);
    }
  }
}

setStyleSheetRule('customCSS', '.have-border { border: 1px solid black;}')
```

Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule