# Dynamically styling pseudo-elements using jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, pseudo-element

I need to change the `margin-top` value of `p::before` dynamically on each image click.
Neither of these questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981211/retrieving-or-changing-css-rules-for-pseudo-elements) / [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481485/changing-css-pseudo-element-styles-via-javascript) / [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330355/javascript-set-css-after-styles) / [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin) nor this [tutorial](http://pankajparashar.com/posts/modify-pseudo-elements-css/) worked for me since I am changing the `margin-top` value not content or colors.

I can't use `attr()` because it's not supported for non-string values according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr).
Creating stylesheet or adding scripting the the header isn't a good idea since I can't reach and modify it again so it's creating tens of style tags and rules and it's messing up with my styling.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

```
p::after {
    top: auto;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-bottom-color: #f9e8a2;
    border-width: 15px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 28px 0 0 -15px;
}
```

Comment: please add a bit html and css

Comment: images can't have a before element and if you are using jquery, why not just create the element if you need to style it dynamically, it's better than trying to style a before element

Comment: @Pete my fault buddy.. it's a p not an img. it's now edited
I am not creating the element because it's animating and moving across the screen.

Comment: You sure none of the workarounds in [4] work for you?

Comment: @BoltClock yes i am sure, because the value of the margin-top rule is calculated then added, i can't add a rule with a static value

Comment: So why can't a created element animate and move across the screen?  All an after is, is a pseudo element that is appended to the end of element

Comment: the element is created at the first click, then it moves by every click using a calculated margin.. until the user closes the div it gets removed. Do you have any suggestion i missed thinking about??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I suggest doing like this, where you dynamically create a `style` element (with a unique id so you can access it over and over) and just update a rule repeatedly

Usage

```
loadStyle('p.clicker::after { margin-top: ' + calculated-value + 'px; }');
```

Script

```
function loadStyle(css) {
  var style = document.querySelector('style[id="lastinbody"]') || document.createElement('style');
  style.id = 'lastinbody';
  style.type = 'text/css';
  if (style.styleSheet){
    style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
  } else {
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
  }
  document.querySelector('body').appendChild(style);
}
```

---

At [this post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41800874/2827823) is a few more versions (which might be consider as a possible duplicate)

Comment: Perfect ! I didn't know that script tags could have an ID
That solved my problem. Thank you